# Geometric Mean: is there a built-in?

Tags: r, statistics, built-in, geometric-mean

I tried to find a built-in for geometric mean but couldn't.

(Obviously a built-in isn't going to save me any time while working in the shell, nor do I suspect there's any difference in accuracy; for scripts I try to use built-ins as often as possible, where the (cumulative) performance gain is often noticeable.

In case there isn't one (which I doubt is the case) here's mine.

```
gm_mean = function(a){prod(a)^(1/length(a))}
```

Comment: Careful about negative numbers and overflows.  prod(a) will under or overflow very quickly.  I tried to time this using a big list and quickly got Inf using your method vs 1.4 with exp(mean(log(x))); the rounding problem can be quite severe.

Comment: i just wrote the function above quickly because i was sure that 5 min after posting this Q, someone would tell me R's built-in for gm. So no built-in so it's certain worth taking the time to re-code in light of your remarks. + 1 from me.

Comment: I just tagged this [tag:geometric-mean] and [tag:built-in], 9 years later.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Here is a vectorized, zero- and NA-tolerant function for calculating geometric mean in R. The verbose `mean` calculation involving `length(x)` is necessary for the cases where `x` contains non-positive values.

```
gm_mean = function(x, na.rm=TRUE){
  exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm=na.rm) / length(x))
}
```

Thanks to @ben-bolker for noting the `na.rm` pass-through and @Gregor for making sure it works correctly.

I think some of the comments are related to a false-equivalency of `NA` values in the data and zeros. In the application I had in mind they are the same, but of course this is not generally true. Thus, if you want to include optional propagation of zeros, and treat the `length(x)` differently in the case of `NA` removal, the following is a slightly longer alternative to the function above.

```
gm_mean = function(x, na.rm=TRUE, zero.propagate = FALSE){
  if(any(x < 0, na.rm = TRUE)){
    return(NaN)
  }
  if(zero.propagate){
    if(any(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE)){
      return(0)
    }
    exp(mean(log(x), na.rm = na.rm))
  } else {
    exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm=na.rm) / length(x))
  }
}
```

Note that it also checks for any negative values, and returns a more informative and appropriate `NaN` respecting that geometric mean is not defined for negative values (but is for zeros). Thanks to commenters who stayed on my case about this.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to pass `na.rm` through as an argument (i.e. let the user decide whether they want to be NA-tolerant or not, for consistency with other R summary functions)?  I'm nervous about automatically excluding zeroes -- I would make that an option as well.

Comment: Perhaps you're right about passing `na.rm` as an option. I'll update my answer. As for excluding zeroes, the geometric mean is undefined for non-positive values, including zeroes. The above is a common fix for geometric mean, in which zeroes (or in this case all non-zeroes) are given a dummy value of 1, which has no effect on the product (or equivalently, zero in the logarithmic sum).

Comment: *I meant a common fix for non-positive values, zero being the most common when geometric mean is being used.

Comment: I thought the effect of a zero would be (as pointed out by @Alan-James-Salmoni below) to force the GM to zero, i.e. `result <- if(any(x==0)) 0 else exp(sum(...))`

Comment: Your `na.rm` pass-through doesn't work as coded... see `gm_mean(c(1:3, NA), na.rm = T)`. You need to remove the `& !is.na(x)` from the vector subset, and since the first arg of `sum` is `...`, you need to pass `na.rm = na.rm` by name, and you also need to exclude `0`'s and `NA`'s from the vector in the `length` call.

Comment: Gregor, good catch on the `...` As for excluding `0`s and `NA`'s -- nope that is as I meant it. I explained above about non-positive values. There's a reason it is `sum(x_trim)/length(x)` and not simply `mean(x_trim)`; where `x_trim` is the non-positive-removed vector

Comment: @PaulMcMurdie As is, `gm_mean(1:3)` gives 1.8, but `gm_mean(c(1:3, NA))` gives 1.6. The presence of `NA` has no effect on the sum, but it does have effect on the length.

Comment: But even if that behavior is desired, because you always exclude `NA` from `x` *before* the sum, your `na.rm` does nothing. `gm_mean(c(1:3, NA))` gives the same result (1.565) for both `na.rm = T` and `na.rm = F`.

Comment: @Gregor I see your point, just removed the `!is.na(x)` from the extractor expression.

Comment: why are you excluding the negative numbers? I think you should return `NaN` if the number of non-NA elements is even and the product is negative, and return a number in all other cases (including all of `x`); also I think you should normalize by the number of non-NA `x`'s, just like regular `mean` does - as-is you're not *removing* NA, but instead substituting it with 1

Comment: @eddi Per wikipedia: "The [geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) only applies to positive numbers in order to avoid taking the root of a negative product, which would result in imaginary numbers, and also to satisfy certain properties about means [...] Note that the definition is unambiguous if one allows 0 (which yields a geometric mean of 0), but may be excluded, as one frequently wishes to take the logarithm of geometric means (to convert between multiplication and addition), and one cannot take the logarithm of 0."

Comment: Won't this code always fail at `if(any(x < 0))` if the input `x` contains NAs ?

Comment: Yep. I missed the edge case when there are no values less than zero AND also NAs. If there are values less than zero then the test works fine. E.g. `if( any(c(NA, 0, 1, 1) < 0) ){message("yay")}` returns instead:
`Error in if (any(c(NA, 0, 1, 1) < 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. I've updated the example so that `any` as `na.rm = TRUE`. This should handle all but the corner case where you're trying to take the geometric mean of all `NA`s... I'm comfortable with that O:-)

Comment: @Gregory  it is incorrect to use NA in the length when na.rm=T since by definition you are removing the missing value. If missing values are kept, then the gm_mean value shall be NA since you have NO clue what the geomean is due to the missing value.

Comment: Beware: for `x` containing only zero(s), like `x <- 0`, `exp(sum(log(x[x>0]), na.rm = TRUE)/length(x))` gives `1` for the geometric mean, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Assuming na.rm = TRUE, wouldn't it have to be something like length(x[!is.na(x) & x > 0])?

Answer (score 100):

No, but there are a few people who have written one, such as [here](http://www.personality-project.org/r/Rfunc/geometric.mean.R).

Another possibility is to use this:

```
exp(mean(log(x)))
```

Comment: Another advantage of using exp(mean(log(x))) is that you can work with long lists of large numbers, which is problematic when using the more obvious formula using prod(). Note that prod(a)^(1/length(a)) and exp(mean(log(a))) give the same answer.

Comment: the link has been fixed

Answer (score 19):

We can use [psych package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=psych) and call *geometric.mean* function.

Comment: `psych::geometric.mean()`

Comment: These functions should take the series and not their growth, at least as an option, I would say.

Answer (score 12):

The

```
exp(mean(log(x)))
```

will work unless there is a 0 in x. If so, the log will produce -Inf (-Infinite) which always results in a geometric mean of 0.

One solution is to remove the -Inf value before calculating the mean:

```
geo_mean <- function(data) {
    log_data <- log(data)
    gm <- exp(mean(log_data[is.finite(log_data)]))
    return(gm)
}
```

You can use a one-liner to do this but it means calculating the log twice which is inefficient.

```
exp(mean(log(i[is.finite(log(i))])))
```

Comment: why calculate the log twice when you can do:
exp(mean(x[x!=0]))

Comment: both approaches get the mean wrong, because the denominator for the mean, `sum(x) / length(x)` is wrong if you filter x and then pass it to `mean`.

Comment: I think filtering is a bad idea unless you explicitly mean to do it (e.g. if I were writing a *general-purpose* function I would not make filtering the default) -- OK if this is a one-off piece of code and you've thought very carefully about what filtering zeroes out actually means in the context of your problem (!)

Comment: By definition a geometric mean of a set of numbers containing zero should be zero! http://math.stackexchange.com/a/91445/221143

Answer (score 6):

I use exactly what Mark says. This way, even with tapply, you can use the built-in `mean` function, no need to define yours! For example, to compute per-group geometric means of data$value:

```
exp(tapply(log(data$value), data$group, mean))
```

Answer (score 4):

The [EnvStats package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=EnvStats) has a function for *geoMean* and *geoSd*.

Answer (score 4):

This version provides more options than the other answers.

- It allows the user to distinguish between results that are not (real) numbers and those that are not available. If negative numbers are present, then the answer won't be a real number, so `NaN` is returned. If it's all `NA` values then the function will return `NA_real_` instead to reflect that a real value is literally not available. This is a subtle difference, but one that might yield (slightly) more robust results.
- The first optional parameter `zero.rm` is intended to allow the user to have zeros affect the output without making it zero. If `zero.rm` is set to `FALSE` and `eta` is set to `NA_real_` (its default value), zeros have the effect of shrinking the result towards one. I don't have any theoretical justification for this - it just seems to make more sense to not ignore the zeros but to "do something" that doesn't involve automatically making the result zero.
- `eta` is a way of handling zeros that was inspired by the following discussion: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/64014/

```r
geomean <- function(x,
                    zero.rm = TRUE,
                    na.rm = TRUE,
                    nan.rm = TRUE,
                    eta = NA_real_) {
    nan.count <- sum(is.nan(x))
     na.count <- sum(is.na(x))
  value.count <- if(zero.rm) sum(x[!is.na(x)] > 0) else sum(!is.na(x))

  #Handle cases when there are negative values, all values are missing, or
  #missing values are not tolerated.
  if ((nan.count > 0 & !nan.rm) | any(x < 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    return(NaN)
  }
  if ((na.count > 0 & !na.rm) | value.count == 0) {
    return(NA_real_)
  }

  #Handle cases when non-missing values are either all positive or all zero.
  #In these cases the eta parameter is irrelevant and therefore ignored.
  if (all(x > 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    return(exp(mean(log(x), na.rm = TRUE)))
  }
  if (all(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    return(0)
  }

  #All remaining cases are cases when there are a mix of positive and zero
  #values.
  #By default, we do not use an artificial constant or propagate zeros.
  if (is.na(eta)) {
    return(exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm = TRUE) / value.count))
  }
  if (eta > 0) {
    return(exp(mean(log(x + eta), na.rm = TRUE)) - eta)
  }
  return(0) #only propagate zeroes when eta is set to 0 (or less than 0)
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details explaining how this differs from/improves on existing solutions?  (I personally wouldn't want to add a heavy dependency like `dplyr` for such a utility unless necessary ...)

Comment: I agree, the ```case_when```s were a little silly, so I removed them and the dependency in favor of ```if```s. I also provided some elaboration.

Comment: I went with your latter idea and changed the default of ```nan.rm``` to ```TRUE``` to align all three ```.rm`` parameters.

Comment: One other stylistic nitpick. `ifelse` is designed for vectorization. With a single condition to check, it would be more idiomatic to use `value.count <- if(zero.rm) sum(x[!is.na(x)] > 0) else sum(!is.na(x))`

Comment: It looks nicer than ```ifelse```, too. Changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case there is missing values in your data, this is not a rare case.
you need to add one more argument.

You may try following code:

```
exp(mean(log(i[ is.finite(log(i)) ]), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exp(mean(log(x1))) == prod(x1)^(1/length(x1))
```