# Add summary mean row in R dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So I have two systems executing two benchmarks from which I collect two metrics.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Benchmark = c("Benchmark1", "Benchmark2"),
              Metric1   = c(120, 200),
              Metric2   = c(200, 150))
df2 <- data.frame(Benchmark = c("Benchmark1", "Benchmark2"),
              Metric1   = c(100, 150),
              Metric2   = c(200, 180))
```

Now I prepare this dataframe for plotting with ggplot

```
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Benchmark") %>%
  gather(Metric,Value,2:5) %>%
  mutate(System = ifelse(grepl(".x", Metric), "System1", "System2"),
         Metric = ifelse(grepl("1" , Metric), "Metric1", "Metric2"))
```

And I can get a nice chart like this

```
ggplot(df %>% filter(Metric == "Metric1"), aes(x = Benchmark, y = Value, fill = System)) + 
       geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image: Nice chart]

Now I want to add a new set of bars with the geomean of those metrics, for each of those systems.

My dataframe needs to contain 2 x 2 = 4 new rows for each (System, Metric) combination containing the geomean of the values of the benchmarks for each (System, Metric) combination.

I know I can use base R to select data frame columns matching a criteria, getting the mean and then manually entering new rows using bind_rows. Is there a more automated way to accomplish this using dplyr? Perhaps with some combination of group_by() with other function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

Wrangled dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Metric, System) %>%
  mutate(GM = gm_mean(Value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(Benchmark, Value) %>%
  gather(x, y, -Metric, -System)

> df2
# A tibble: 12 x 4
    Metric  System          x        y
     <chr>   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Metric1 System1         GM 154.9193
 2 Metric1 System2         GM 122.4745
 3 Metric2 System1         GM 173.2051
 4 Metric2 System2         GM 189.7367
 5 Metric1 System1 Benchmark1 120.0000
 6 Metric1 System2 Benchmark1 100.0000
 7 Metric2 System1 Benchmark1 200.0000
 8 Metric2 System2 Benchmark1 200.0000
 9 Metric1 System1 Benchmark2 200.0000
10 Metric1 System2 Benchmark2 150.0000
11 Metric2 System1 Benchmark2 150.0000
12 Metric2 System2 Benchmark2 180.0000
```

Function for calculating geometric mean was taken from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602583/geometric-mean-is-there-a-built-in).

Plot (faceted to show both Metric1 & Metric2 at the same time):

```
ggplot(df2, 
       aes(x = x, y = y, fill = System)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(Metric~.)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't think of combining spread + gather one more time to achieve this.

(so, there's no command that unites this functionality into a single one?)

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Benchmark") %>%
  gather(Metric,Value,2:5) %>%
  mutate(System = ifelse(grepl(".x", Metric), "System1", "System2"),
         Metric = ifelse(grepl("1" , Metric), "Metric1", "Metric2"))

df<-df%>%group_by(Benchmark,Metric)%>%
          summarise(Value = mean(Value,na.rm=TRUE))%>%
          mutate(System = "Mean")%>%
          bind_rows(.,df)


ggplot(df %>% filter(Metric == "Metric1"), aes(x = Benchmark, y = Value, fill = System)) + 
       geom_col(position = "dodge")
```