# How to Calculate Geometric Mean for Specific Quarters

Tags: r

I am finding hard time calculating Geometric date for each column for the specific years. I had to calculate that for multiple columns. It was done in excel and now we like to move to r for broader audience Below are the formulas used in Excel

```
(GEOMEAN(1+DK45:DK48)^4)^(1/4)-1
```

I tried applying mean.geometric formula from performance library which give exactly the result but not sure how to apply that by different quarters on whole column

```
  TotalReturn %>% 
  mutate(mpgGM = rollapply(l12420, 3, geometric.mean, fill=NA, 
  align="left"))
```

My sample data set is

```
structure(list(Quarter = structure(c(18717, 18808, 18900, 18992, 
19082, 19173, 19265, 19357, 19447, 19538, 19630, 19722), class = "Date"), 
    A = c(0.043, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.046, 0.048, 0.049, 
    0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.051), B = c(-0.002, -0.001, 0.002, 0.008, 
    0.015, 0.02, 0.024, 0.025, 0.025, 0.023, 0.022, 0.022)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the expected result

```
2021 Q4 4.06%
2022 Q4 4.68%
2023 Q4 5.04%
```

Comment: what is `l12420` in the data and`geometric.mean` function?

Comment: Your description says to apply for different quarters, but why is `Q4` only `filtered`

Comment: Are you talking about the geometric mean of the values in `A` and `B` column in each row? Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @jay.sf  I am looking geometric mean for whole year

Comment: @gurtej see the edits to my answer

Comment: @gurtej Have you seen my edit? Does this answer your question now?

Comment: @jay.sf Sorry for late reply. My laptop was not with me. Calculations are working as expected. Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: @gurtej Great, glad to help! Consider to [**accept answers**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/371738) that solved questions are marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate` with [function for geometric mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555105/6574038). We can get the year of `substr`ing from 1st to 4th character.

```
> gm_mean <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE) {
+   exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm=na.rm)/length(x))
+ }
> aggregate(. ~ cbind(year=substr(dat$Quarter, 1, 4)), dat, gm_mean)[-2]
  year          A          B
1 2021 0.04374784 0.06324555
2 2022 0.04671022 0.02059767
3 2023 0.05024815 0.02296827
```

To get `%` display we can use `sprintf` with the appropriate format string.

```
> aggregate(. ~ cbind(year=substr(dat$Quarter, 1, 4)), dat, 
+           \(x) sprintf("%.1f%%", gm_mean(x)*100))[-2]
  year    A    B
1 2021 4.4% 6.3%
2 2022 4.7% 2.1%
3 2023 5.0% 2.3%
```

---

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(Quarter = structure(c(18717, 18808, 18900, 18992, 
19082, 19173, 19265, 19357, 19447, 19538, 19630, 19722), class = "Date"), 
    A = c(0.043, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.046, 0.048, 0.049, 
    0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.051), B = c(-0.002, -0.001, 0.002, 0.008, 
    0.015, 0.02, 0.024, 0.025, 0.025, 0.023, 0.022, 0.022)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```